# Start Tween when other Tween reaches certain position AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I'm trying to create a simple slideshow of 3 images going from left to right.
I want to check if the last image is on stage ( so the image3.x = 0 ) in order to start the new Tween.

I thought it would be something a simple as the following code, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
function Start() {

    if(image3.x == 0){
        var myTween:Tween = new Tween(image, "x", None.easeNone, -140, 640, 10, true);
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Start);
```

Comment: Look into [Greensock Tweenlite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite). Look into the the [OnUpdate, OnUpdateParams, OnComplete and OnCompleteParams](https://greensock.com/asdocs/) properties of the GS Tweens.

Answer (score 0):

Split the original `Tween` in two parts, from -140 to 0 and from 0 to 640.

```
var tween:Tween = new Tween(image, "x", None.easeNone, -140, 0, 10, true);
```

Wait for it to finish:

```
tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onZeroReached);
```

Then do the second part plus whatever else you want to do:

```
function onZeroReached(te:TweenEvent):void
{
    tween = new Tween(image, "x", None.easeNone, 0, 640, 10, true);

    // do additional stuff here
}
```

code untested

Comment: you can only split the Tween this way if there's no easing

Comment: If no reference of the tween is kept anywhere it will qualify for GC and eventually stop working. Same problem with PO code.

Comment: @BotMaster good point, fixed that by just reusing the old non-local variable.